# how to add multi function using setAttrubute?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a problem, with this line of code how to add multi function using set attribute method ?
I can get only 1 of them working at time, is there something missing or the syntax is wrong ?
thanks.

```js
const listEl = document.createElement('li');
listEl.setAttribute('onblur', `updateItem(${index}, ${row})`, `deleteItemOnClick(${index}, ${row})`);
```

Comment: do not use setAttribute for events. That is what addEventListener is for.

Comment: You do not set multiple things. Each one needs to be its own

Answer (score 1):

You should be using addEventListener to bind events. If you want to call both this onblur, make a function and call both methods.

```
const listEl = document.createElement('li');
listEl.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  updateItem(index, row);
  deleteItemOnClick(index, row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these code, To how to add multi-function using setAttrubute?

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

Call the function:

```
setAttributes(elem, {"src": "http://example.com/something.jpeg", "height": "100%", ...});
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.